# JavaScript function not working in iOS

Tags: javascript, html, objective-c, ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I create the NSString that contains JavaScript.

```
NSString *   someString =@"<!DOCTYPE html>\n        <html>\n       <body> \n    


    <h1>My Web Page</h1> \n       <p id=\"myPar\">I am a paragraph.</p><div id=\"myDiv\">I am a div.</div> \n       <p>        <button type=\"button\" onclick=\"myFunction()\">Try it</button> \n       </p>        <script type=\"text/javascript\">        function myFunction()        {            document.getElementById(\"myPar\").innerHTML=\"Hello Dolly\";            document.getElementById(\"myDiv\").innerHTML=\"How are you?\";\n        }        </script>       <p>When you click on \"Try it\", the two elements will change.</p>       \n </body> \n       </html>\n";
```

After that, I set the e-mail body using that string.

```
        MFMailComposeViewController* Apicker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
            if (Apicker != nil)
            {


                Apicker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    }
     [Apicker setMessageBody:someString isHTML:YES];
 [self presentModalViewController:Apicker animated:YES];
```

I send the e-mail.

My problem is,when I check that mail and press the `Try it` button, it is not working.

If I use simple HTML in  the `someString` object, it is working.

Why is JavaScript not working in the e-mail?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most email clients (iPhone included) do not support JavaScript for security reasons.

For example, one could embed a malicious script in an e-mail that reports back to the sender if the e-mail is read, allowing spammers to verify e-mail addresses.

Using the CSS pseudo-class [`:focus`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/%3afocus), you can achieve something similar in CSS.

Although this has its limitations (such as not being able to place the button after the HTML elements instead of in front of them), it is the only alternative to asking the recipient to click trough to a web page; e-mails are limited to HTML and CSS.

**HTML**:

```
<button type="button">Try it</button>
<p id="myPar"><span class=oldtext>I am a paragraph.</span><span class=newtext>Hello Dolly</span></p>


<div id="myDiv"><span class=oldtext>I am a div.</span><span class=newtext>How are you?</span></div>

<p>When you click on "Try it", the two elements will change.</p>
```

**CSS:**

```
/*
    Default state
*/
button+#myPar .oldtext,button+*+#myDiv .oldtext{

    display:inline;/* Not required because <span> tags are inline by default. Use if you use block-level elements and / or elements that are styled as block-level elements */
}

button+#myPar .newtext,button+*+#myDiv .newtext{

    display:none;
}


/*
    Button click effect
*/
button:focus+#myPar .oldtext,button:focus+*+#myDiv .oldtext{

    display:none;
}

button:focus+#myPar .newtext,button:focus+*+#myDiv .newtext{

    display:inline;
}
```

↪ [View this example at JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7uwmb/1/)

***Note**: according to [can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-sel2), the CSS used in this example is iOS compatible. It will **not** work in IE < 9.*

Answer (score 1):

Most email clients (iPhone included) do not support JavaScript for security reasons.

For example, one could embed a malicious script in an e-mail that reports back to the sender if the e-mail is read, allowing spammers to verify e-mail addresses.

Comment: so,How can i do same functionality without javascript?I testing it on iPad.

Comment: @user2428118 , Yes you are right so , how can i create such button in html body without javascript.do u have any idea ?

Comment: @kEvin: Maybe you can accomplish this using CSS3 technologies. I'm not sure sure about their support on iOS though. [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/7PRwc/)

Comment: @user2428118,Thanks for suggestion but CSS3 is only for designing , How can i create function in html without scripting language ?If all Scripting languages are disable in email.

Comment: Sorry - only HTML + CSS are allowed. I will post an answer with an example how you can accomplish something similar to what you want using CSS3, but you are bound by these limitations. If you don't want that, consider linking to a web page instead of trying to put this code in an e-mail.

Comment: @user2428118,ok I understand it.Please send the demo for HTML + CSS.